# two images overlapping not correctly

Tags: html, css

my output -[image]

I want -[image]

But as you see, output is not exactly what i want. i want two picture to overlap at the same place, so a portion of one picture gets obscured by another picture

My css code -

```
.shamne {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pichone {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

my html code -

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6 col-12 mb-4">
  <div>
    <img src="images/fake_m.png" class="shamne" />
    <img src="images/tamim1.png" class="pichone" />
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: After Khalil's suggestion, i used his code but the output is -
[image]

UPDATE : macK is a lifesaver, his solution worked charm for me

Comment: make the image holder div position relative otherwise the absolute image will not position correctly

Comment: @Pete,sorry man, i didnt understand your solution. Can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: whenever you position an element absolutely, an ancestor of that element must be positioned - in this case you want the image container to be relative and then you can position you images absolutely - relative to the parent (also you probably want to use bottom instead of top if you want to align it with the bottom of the other image).  [Read this for more understanding about positioning](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the markup you can set both images as `position: absolute` with and the parent div with `position: relative` with a width and height.

You also might need to adjust the two images positions with `top` `bottom` `left` and `right` placement afterwards to your liking and make sure you set a lower `z-index` for the background.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="overlay" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/image-placeholder-png-2.png" />
  <img class="background" src="https://placehold.it/400x400" />
</div>
```

If you can change the markup, alternatively, you can use a `background-image` in the CSS on the wrapper element and save an extra `<img>` element. That would be a more semantically correct way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6 col-12 mb-4">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <img src="images/fake_m.png" class="shamne" />
  <img src="images/tamim1.png" class="pichone" />
 </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper{
 width: 100%; 
 height: max-content;
 position: relative;
}
.shamne{
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.pichone{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Comment: can you kindly check my edited post? Your solution unfortunately aint working :/

Comment: Can you create a codepen? I may be able to help you better that way.

Comment: Indeed, a CodePen tends to make it **much** easier for us to help, since it allows us to easily test the code.

Comment: Code without explanation rarely makes for a good answer.